# Using EBS volume instead of Ephemeral disks when creating an AMI image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am a beginner, so this question might be stupid. Basically, I have created an EBS volume and attached it to the instance I am running on EC2. Then, I transferred all the information from the Ephemeral disk to the EBS volume by mounting it to a temporary mount. Then, I unmounted the ephemeral disk's mount point and mounted the EBS volume at that mount point. 
After that, I updated /etc/fstab so that the EBS volume will be mounted at /mnt rather than the ephemeral disk. After this, I created a snapshot of the EBS volume and then processed on creating the AMI.

When I launch an instance from the image I just created, the Ephemeral disk gets mounted at /mnt rather than the EBS volume.

Am I missing something here? I am simply trying to switch from ephemeral disks to EBS volume for data persistence. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to figure it out.
When I create an a m1.xlarge instance from the image I created, I made sure to remove the ephemeral storage devices manually before launching the instance and this fixed my problem! :D